# Build location-independent GCC binaries

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, c

I have some problems with GCC. I want a portable version of GCC because the PC I use for programming cannot be connected to Internet due to some driver issues. So, I read an article on how to compile gcc from source to make it a portable version and followed it. But when I copied the directory where I built GCC to my PC and tried to compile a simple C program,  it gives an error saying "`stdio.h` no such file or directory" so definitely my portable GCC is not working properly. I used the arguments like `--disable-shared`, `--enable-static` etc... as given in the article but still I know that the compiled version is not portable. Can someone please tell me how to compile a portable version of GCC which I can then copy to my PC?

***Note:*** The PC on which I need GCC is running Fedora 23. It doesn't have any C compiler pre-installed and due to same reasons, I am not able to compile driver for my wifi adapter. So, please suggest a method which doesn't require my main PC to be connected to Internet.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "portable" version of GCC is. Can you elaborate? "I want a portable version of GCC because the PC I use for programming cannot be connected to Internet due to some driver issues." Why does GCC require the net?

Comment: I need a version which I can copy to other systems.  That is, I want to compile it on one PC and then use those compiled version on another PC

Comment: Oh. That sounds like a somewhat demanding requirement. Presumably you want the compiled executables to run on whatever your target machines are. Suggestion: fix your driver issues and get on the net. Have you already posted about those driver issues? If not, you could post a question here.

Comment: Can't you build the driver module on some other system running Fedora 23 on which you can install GCC properly?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(    The other pc I use has Linux Mint 17.3. This is the link to article I read:      http://m.wikihow.com/Manually-Build-GNU-Compiler-Collection-from-Scratch-on-Linux-Mint-Static-Edition

Comment: You forgot to include a link to the article you followed.

Comment: I remember there's a way to force a binary to be compiled with a static libc (--disable-shared --enable-static usually still dynamically links a shared libc due to size constraints), but can't remember what I used at the moment. If I can find it, I'll make an answer, but maybe that can give you something to search for.

Comment: Hey,. I managed to get the PC connected to Internet by simply using USB Tethering via my phone...  I know I should have done it earlier but I didn't think of it..... Thnx everybody for your suggestions :)